# express-jwt not validating token after updating express-jwt

Tags: express, jwt, express-jwt

I recently updated `jsonwebtoken` and `express-jwt` .
`jsonwebtoken@8.5.1`
`express-jwt@7.7.5`

Now valid tokens do not validate anymore. Here is my `auth middleware`. The only change I had to make here was adding `algorithms: ["HS256"]` as this now required with the latest version.

```
var { expressjwt: jwt } = require("express-jwt");

const getTokenFromHeaders = (req) => {
  const { headers: { authorization } } = req;
  
  // console.log('auth called with req', req.headers);
  console.log('Token: ', req.headers.authorization);
  if(authorization && authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Token') {
    return authorization.split(' ')[1];
  }
  return null;
};

const auth = {
  required: jwt({
    secret: 'secret',
    algorithms: ["HS256"],
    userProperty: 'payload',
    getToken: getTokenFromHeaders
  }),
  optional: jwt({
    secret: 'secret',
    algorithms: ["HS256"],
    userProperty: 'payload',
    getToken: getTokenFromHeaders,
    credentialsRequired: false,
  }),
};
module.exports = auth;
```

I am calling the middleware like this

```
router.get('/get_content', auth.required, (req, res, next) => {
 
  // getting 500 error before getting to the next function!

   res.json({});
});
```

I checked that the header is sending a valid token. Not sure why this is suddenly a problem.
I generate the token like this in the User schema:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

UsersSchema.methods.generateJWT = function() {
  const today = new Date();
  const expirationDate = new Date(today);
  expirationDate.setDate(today.getDate() + 60);

  return jwt.sign({
    email: this.email,
    id: this._id,
    isVerified: this.isVerified,
    exp: parseInt(expirationDate.getTime() / 1000)
  }, 'secret');
}
```

Here is a token that should work (validated at https://jwt.io/)

`eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6Im1lMDAxQHRvbm5lLnRvIiwiaWQiOiI2MmM4OGJkYjdiMjk4YTM5YWUzNjE2NTciLCJpc1ZlcmlmaWVkIjp0cnVlLCJleHAiOjE2NjI1MTU4NDEsImlhdCI6MTY1NzMzMTg0MX0.TYeE8lEF7_RqqYBPBSdf_gaMoYqa2o2Ef_CBw5ZeKT0`

Comment: It works for me with the given token. Does your request really have an `Authorization: Token ey...` header, not `Authorization: Bearer ey...`?

Comment: Hi Heiko - That was the issue. Using postman to generate the request showed me that the Token had a `Bearer` prefix. Thanks!!